# Price for CloudWatch custom metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the rate for creating a custom metric in AWS CloudWatch.

Is it free of charges?

I don't want a detailed monitoring in my CloudWatch metric.

Answer (score 2):

Its $0.50 per month per metric. I don't think you have the choice of detailed or not with custom metrics. That is only applicable to basic EC2 metrics.

Current prices are available at the [Amazon Cloudwatch website](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/).

Comment: I don't think it's correct to publish prices here, since they are subject to change. Instead, this is the link: http://aws.amazon.com/pricing/cloudwatch/

Answer (score 0):

Basic Monitoring can be enable on an EC2 instance and is included free of charge.

You can track up to 10 custom metrics for free as of August 18, 2021. Best to double check the allotment of the free tier and price of the paid tier directly on the AWS website: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/.

There are a few gotchas to be aware of when it comes to metrics. The community maintains a resource on cloud costs [here][1]. You can view CloudWatch specific details here: https://handbook.vantage.sh/aws/services/cloudwatch-pricing/